# JS/Jest: how to test for conditional booleans?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a JS file that had:

`player = videojs(VIDEO_PLAYER_ID, VIDEO_JS_CONFIG);`

I since put that in the `else` of a conditional:

```
 if (showIVSPlayer) {
    const ivsPlayer = new IVSPlayer({
      id: VIDEO_PLAYER_ID,
      config: VIDEO_JS_CONFIG,
      ivsTech: win.registerIVSTech,
    });
    ivsPlayer.init();

    player = ivsPlayer.player;

  } else {

    player = videojs(VIDEO_PLAYER_ID, VIDEO_JS_CONFIG);

  }
```

When I run tests on it, it shows me there is no coverage on the new lines where `showIVSPlayer` would be true but how can I have that test covered and still have the `else` covered as well?

Comment: you need two tests, one for each branch

Comment: @bel3atar the original `player` got created in the `beforeEach`.  I guess there's no way to make two tests without ripping it out of the beforeEach?

Comment: you could overwrite it inside the second test and restore it like it was before by using a temporary variable. it's not perfect but it gets the job done